# Why doesn't ---.*--- select everything between --- inclusive?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Some text here. This text is not replaced.

---

And then a wild block appears!
It has stuff in it that I'm trying to replace.

---

The block is no more. Nothing to replace here.
```

And I'd like to replace everything between `---` and `---`. So I'm trying:

```
text=File.open('myfile')
text.sub(/---.*---/, 'replacement')
```

But that doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify "multiline" option in your pattern to make dot symbol match newline characters:

Thus, your code should look like

```
text.sub(/---.*?---/m, 'replacement')
```

See [example](http://rubular.com/r/XGhwKNrvM5)

Comment: Don't you mean `/m` (multiline)? Also, perhaps make `.*` non-greedy (`.*?`) in case there is more than one `"---"`-delimited block. I don't believe Ruby supports the `s` option.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, exactly. It is very strange, but "dot symbol match newline characters" is for multiline mode in Ruby, not sinle line like in other languages. My fault, updating the answer.